# Formulario en html y css

Tags: html, css, formularios

tengo una inquietud y es que quiero quitarle este borde que le sale a mi formulario cada vez que selecciono un campo para empezar a escribir. Gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra un [repro] del código que tienes para el formulario. Lee [ask]. Además, pon un título más descriptivo a tu pregunta, para así lograr captar mayor atención.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si, como parece es una caja de texto y te refieres al borde del foco, entonces prueba esto:

```
input:focus{
outline: none;
}
```

Comment: En general es mala práctica solo quitar el `:focus`, es recomendable añadir otro representativo/indicativo que nos ayude a saber el elemento que esta enfocado. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:focus#focus_outline_none)

Comment: Me funcionó, mil gracias